# Neo4j create multiple nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j to build a huge graph database (over a million nodes). The way I'm doing it right now is running a cypher `CREATE (n {property:'value'})` query for each of the node. As expected, this is quite an inefficient method and it takes lots of time. Can somebody suggest me some alternative method to overcome this issue? I've heard that Neo4j also provides some default batch interface to create multiple nodes. I'm currently using this version of code (including the relationship):

`create (a { name: "a" })-[:rel1]->(b {name : "b"}),(c {name: "c"})-[:rel2]->(d {name:"d"}),...`

Is it an efficient method or are there any better methods?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5):

Two alternatives I'd consider:

1. Use the `LOAD CSV` support: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-load-csv.html
2. Use a single paramaterized Cypher statement, and supply an array of parameters: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-create.html#create-create-multiple-nodes-with-a-parameter-for-their-properties

Otherwise there is the batch inserter, as mentioned.

Comment: Is the single parametrized Cypher statement recommended? Won't the array of maps be a really huge one for Neo4j to handle? Also, my data is in a scipy sparse matrix format (because it's more efficient). That's why I was thinking whether converting to csv would be a good alternative?

Comment: Yes - a single array of maps will likely be problematic for huge amounts. CSV should be ok, or otherwise the batch inserter as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

There is an overview on the Neo4j website: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import

But to be short, for more than a million nodes I would say:

If you can code in Java:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html

else:

https://github.com/jexp/batch-import

Comment: Is there a way in python to run the batch? I'm sorry for being a bit over curious.

Comment: The CVS batch inserter is just run via a shell script and some csv input files

Comment: As of the 3.0.0 release, other client libraries, such as the .NET one, have access to the batch insert api's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unwind` to your advantage.
Assuming you are using the Java API, here's a small snippet using Groovy

```
List<Map<String, Object>> props = yourList.collect {["prop1": it.prop1, "prop2":it.prop2]}
String q = "UNWIND {props} AS p create(a {name: p.prop1})-[:rel1]->(b {name: p.prop2}) "
neo4jOperations.query(q, ["props" : props])
```

I've had great success with this method. You should be able to see a speedup of 5-30 times depending on your batch size